# Prometheus reports a different value for node_memory_Active_bytes and free -b

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm quite new to Prometheus, so this is possibly a silly question - but here goes.

When I request node_memory_Active_bytes and node_memory_MemTotal_bytes I get:

```
node_memory_Active_bytes{instance="10.1.4.9:9100",job="node-exporter"}  3257815040

(..and..)

node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="10.1.4.9:9100",job="node-exporter"}    16509550592
```

However, on the box, if I run `free -b`, I get the following:

```
$ free -b
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    16509550592  2264915968  6787731456    59121664  7456903168 14140530688
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I'm struggling to maps prometheus's view of memory with the actual machine's view. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. The total's match, but the free

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Equivalent queries for `free -b` command:

- total: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes`
- used: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemFree_bytes - node_memory_Buffers_bytes - node_memory_Cached_bytes - node_memory_SReclaimable_bytes`
- shared: `node_memory_Shmem_bytes`
- free: `node_memory_MemFree_bytes`
- buff/cache: `node_memory_Buffers_bytes + node_memory_Cached_bytes + node_memory_SReclaimable_bytes`
- available: `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`

Comment: You save my day! This should be the right answer.

Comment: The `used` value from `free` correlates with:

`node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`


Not as stated by this answer:

`node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemFree_bytes - node_memory_Buffers_bytes - node_memory_Cached_bytes - node_memory_SReclaimable_bytes`

Comment: The man page even states `Used or unavailable memory (calculated as total -
              available)` https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html

Answer (score 9):

I think you're confusing "active" memory with "used" memory, aren't you? They're different things.

See more info about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305606/linux-inactive-memory).

To get "used" memory with Prometheus Node Exporter calculate:

```
node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes
```

Comment: Ahh! Makes sense, it's still a bit out though.
`node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes = 2394025984`

`used = 2282270720`

Any reason for that? This happens consistently over a fair sample of time.

Comment: Uhm... I don't know :-(

Comment: The discrepancy is possibly due to the estimated nature of `available`. From the man page: 
Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache or free fields, this field takes into account page cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)